# Pentaho Data Integration - REST Client Step

Tags: rest, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to make a request to an API. I have tested it on  Postman, and it's working fine. What a I would like to achieve is make a similar process on Pentaho Data Integration, I guess I should use the REST Cliente step.

I have seen a couple of videos and asked question on forums about this step. I had a running request on other free access API using this step on Pentaho, but now I'm trying to do the same with this new one. Anyone may help to do it?

I attached screenshots about how I have tested it on Postman. Thank's in advanced.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaPth.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the image you have shared looks like you are trying to do a post.

Either way the below setup could help you achieve that.

You can probably have below approach.

```
Generate Rows > Rest Client > Table
```

And with that, you can have API URL and auth info on generate row step, define fields on the REST Client Step and insert the data into a table.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I completlely agree. The problem is I can't set the REST Client Step Up. It's not responding correctly. I can't do the POST. I can't get how to define the Step correctly passing the parameters from the Generate Rows Step.